# Clustering trajectory patterns with lot of missing values

Tags: clustering, panel-data, data-imputation

Is there a problem looking for clusters of trajectory patterns in longitudinal data, when much of the longitudinal values were imputed from the baseline data?

Comment: That depends on your clustering algorithm; what are you using? If you want inspiration try [this](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~vbogorny/acmsac2008.pdf).